# boost::signals2 slot as a non-static function member?

Tags: c++, boost, non-static, boost-signals2

I have been playing around with `boost::signals2` for learning purposes lately, and I was wondering whether I could connect signals to a **non-static** slot located within a class (like I could in Qt). Consider the following:

```
class Worker {
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void (const std::string &)> SendMessage;
public:
    typedef SendMessage::slot_type SendMessageSlotType;
    boost::signals2::connection connect(const SendMessageSlotType &slot) {
        return send_message.connect(slot);
    }
private:
    SendMessage send_message;
};

class Controller {
public:
    Controller() {
        worker.connect(&Controller::print);
    }
private:
    static void print(const std::string &message) {
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
    }

    Worker worker;
};
```

Now I would want to make `Controller::print` a non-static member. With `boost::thread` for example, this can be achieved using `boost::bind`; is there any way to do this with `boost::signals2`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just:

```
class Controller {
public:
    Controller() {
        worker.connect(boost::bind(&Controller::print, this, _1));
    }
private:
    void print(const std::string &message) {
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
    }

    Worker worker;
};
```